# SQL Server Select Query to display all records sorted by latest record inserted or updated

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called Employee with following columns and records in database

```
id     login_time                  logout_time 
1     23/6/2013 9:00 
3     23/6/2013 9:20               23/6/2013 1:00
2     23/6/2013 1:30
```

But i want to display above table records as per latest updated record, below is sample output.

```
id     login_time                  logout_time 
2     23/6/2013 1:30
3     23/6/2013 9:20               23/6/2013 1:00
1     23/6/2013 9:00
```

Could anybody please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming i've understood your question. If you're wanting to order dependent on values in both columns you could use a conditional operator on the order by, for example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Employee
ORDER BY 
    CASE
      WHEN login_time > logout_time THEN login_time 
      ELSE logout_time
    END DESC
```

Ideally however, if you want to order by the last 'updated' record. Personally I would revisit the database design and have a 'DateUpdated' column that gets populated when a value is updated and you can simply order by that instead.

Comment: thanks @JBond, above query is working correctly when both column login_time and logout_time have data, but if logout_time is not filled then record order is not displaying correctly. i tried apending this line WHEN login_time > logout_time OR logout_time = 0 THEN login_time, but dint succeed. could you please do the needful

Comment: I got it perfectly by appending WHEN login_time > logout_time OR logout_time IS NULL THEN login_time . thanks a lot @JBond for giving such a nice idea..

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Employee order by login_time  desc
```

Comment: thanks @Polina, but if logout_time will be latest then above query will not give the correct output. I want that whichever time is latest display according to that.